# Gerrit + Gitlab

Tags: git

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber se alguém já chegou a fazer integração do gerrit com gitlab, andei pesquisando e encontrei algumas possíveis formas de fazer que saber qual seria mais adequada, usando mode de replicação e também algo similar ao gitweb. Tenho hoje meu gerrit funcionando com meus projetos sem problema, porém não da para visualizar fontes, abrir issue, ter acesso a wiki e etc., então resolvi colocar o gitlab para fazer esse meio de campo. O que acham? Alguém tem alguma recomendação. Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Sim, acredito que rapidamente.

Instale gitlab e o gerrit.

```
1. Crie seu repositório no GITLAB.
2. git clone --mirror <url do repositorio gitlab>
3. Crie seu projeto no GERRIT.
4. git push --mirror <url do projeto no gerrit>
5. Configure o plugin de replicação do GERRIT, isso vai replicar suas alterações para o GITLAB.
```

NOTA : VOcê pode usar o plugin GERRIT OAUTH para autenticar usando o GITLAB e o JENKINS para verificar o status da BUILD.

fonte:
https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+doc/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md